# Can an AngularJS directive access a controller instance?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

AngularJS has recently added support for a new "controller as" syntax which seems to be intended as a replacement for `$scope`:

```
var app = angular.module("example", []);
app.controller("ExCtrl", function () {
    this.property = "some value";
    /* Previously you would have to inject $scope and use
    $scope.property = "some value"; */
});
```

When you have a directive that occurs within a view that has a controller attached to it and you want to share data between the directive and the model, you could previously use `$scope`:

```
app.directive("exDirective", function () {
    return function (scope) {
        scope.property2 = "another value";
    };
});
```

Is there a way to use the "controller as" syntax and allow directives occurring within views using that controller to access its scope?

Comment: "controller as" isn't intended to replace, but to augment, scope...

Comment: So if within a view you need a directive that accesses a model from the controller bound to the view there is no point using "controller-as" and you may as well stick with `$scope` (or end up with some of your data on the controller instance and some on the scope)?

Comment: You can do it either way--like many things in angular, there's only guidance and best approaches, not strict rules. The model I've been following is "behavior on controller, data and data manipulation on scope". (think: filter functions, results from $http, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `controller as` syntax will place the controller in the scope with the given name. Any scope that prototypically inherits that scope, will also inherit the controller.

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/j5P77/

Directives with isolated scope could still use the controller with the (inelegant in my opinion) `$parent` scope.

Comment: I don't think this really answers my question. Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HFGBW/). Is it possible to access data assigned to `this` in the controller from a directive `link` function?

Comment: Exactly as I said, see updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HFGBW/1/ (and your console :)

Comment: Ahh, thanks! I thought I might be misunderstanding your answer. That is what I was looking for, and I'm not sure how I missed it when I was logging `scope` within `link` before.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I agree its in elegant, but else can someone do?

Comment: @Tushar: Depends on your case... You can pass the controller to the isolated scope (it is a scope variable after all), you can require the controller from the directive...

Answer (score 2):

The "controller as" features publishes your controller into $scope with the name given. So in your example if you had `ng-controller="ExCtrl as ctrl"` then in your directive you should be able to access property2 using

```
scope.ctrl.property2 = "another value";
```

This is not really the recommended way to go about it though as it then tightly couples the directive with your controller. A better approach would be to either use isolated scope and pass in the property via an attribute or use a shared service to share data.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I agree on the tightly coupled point. This was just me trying to get a better idea of how "controller as" actually works, which I do now understand.